# FAB button not showing on a nested scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying show fab more button inside the nested scroll view.I  have searched for many solutions but not found any solution which I can able to show fab more button in right bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_close"
                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Filter All Order"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/billBlock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            //many inner layout
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/grey_10" />



                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/print_payment_list"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey_20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/fabFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_mic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@color/grey_80"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey_20"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@color/grey_80"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey_20"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

        <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"-->
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have multiple views inside one parent of nested scroll view .scroll and all working fine .only issue is fab is not positioned in a bottom right position

can anyone help me how I can achieve this? since am new to android.T hanks

[image]

i need fab bar to be placed like this .This is sample image from google

Comment: will you show screenshot and what you need ?

Comment: @sushildlh.updated question.thanks

Comment: you need like that ?

Comment: i need to achieve in nested scroll view since for me nested scroll view needed because i am using bottomsheet view

Comment: if i add fab bar without nested then it works

Comment: try below answer

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_close"
                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Filter All Order"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fabFrame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/billBlock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            //many inner layout
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/grey_10" />



                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/print_payment_list"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey_20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_mic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@color/grey_80"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey_20"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@color/grey_80"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey_20"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

        <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"-->
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Always used linear layout for continuous Views and use Framelayout or Relative Layout when you what to show something position like right or bottom.

Comment: @sushildlh.thank you so much for the effort  .problem is now the fab is coming below nested scroll view not inside scroll view

Comment: you want fab inside scroll View bottom of the Parent Layout ? Use Relative layout instead of Linear layout .